# SteamID64 minimum and maximum length

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Simple question that no one seems to know.

**What is the minimum and maximum length of SteamID64?**

Comment: All ID's ive checked are 17 characters long but I need more information then that.

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID

Answer (score 19):

Minimum: `0x0110000100000000`

Maximum: `0x01100001FFFFFFFF`

Length is always 17 decimal digits.

Comment: The lowest is almost correct.
0x110000100000000 = https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197960265729.
0x0110000100000001 = https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197960265730.